# 'requirements-checker' is not a recognised when running composer install on windows

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony6

I develop my Symfony 6.4 project on both windows and a macbook, and when I run `composer install` or `composer update`, it gives me the error of 'requirements-checker' is not recognised in cmd. Below is my composer.json file - I cannot figure out why this is not working as it works fine on my macos machine.

```
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "amphp/http-client": "4.2.1",
        "babdev/pagerfanta-bundle": "^4.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.10",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.16",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^4.8",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.6",
        "gladcodes/keygen": "^1.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "*",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^4.24",
        "pagerfanta/doctrine-orm-adapter": "^4.2",
        "pagerfanta/twig": "^4.2",
        "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.20",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.24",
        "symfony/asset": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^2.0",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^2.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.7",
        "twig/string-extra": "^3.7",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "requirements-checker": "script",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "6.4.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.4",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.4.*"
    }
}
```

I have looked into searching this issue and checked with composer too but no one else seems to be having this problem so I am unsure of what I have wrong

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Did you check whether it was installed properly in the vendor folder?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the checker has seen the last updates in Nov 2021. Maybe you should no longer use it?